# Using regex to add styling to text

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, ecmascript-6

Having a text input, it is wanted to show the text in bold if it is situated between two exclamation signs.

For example: `a!a!bb!c!c` will be a**a**bb**c**c. The text situated between ! will be made bold.

This is the code:

```
const arr = "this! i!s the i!npu!t";

if (arr.includes('!')) {
  result = arr.replace(/\!(\w+)\!/g, '<b>$1</b>');
}
```

it seems to work fine if there is a contiguous string but if there are words with spaces between them it doesn't work fine.

Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: `\w` is the regex escape for a "word character." That wouldn't include a space. To include spaces you can do `[\w ]` (capture group including `\w` and a space character) for just space, or `[\w\s]` to include other space-like characters, like tab and carriage return. Or you could do `.` if you want all characters including punctuation and stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First, you do not need to escape `!`.
2. Second, you replace `\w+` by `[^!]+` because `\w+` is egal `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`.

So, you could try the following regex.

```
!([^!]+)!
```

```js
const arr = "this! i!s the i!npu!t";

if (arr.includes('!')) {
  result = arr.replace(/!([^!]+)!/g, '<b>$1</b>');
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t work because you are using `\w`, which only matches certain characters, when you really want to match all characters other than `!`. The way to do that is to use `[^!]`.

That is `[^`, followed by all the characters you do *not* want to match, followed by `]`.

Corrected code:

```
const arr = "this! i!s the i!npu!t";

if (arr.includes('!')) {
  result = arr.replace(/\!(\w+)\!/g, '<b>$1</b>');
}
```

Comment: prove it. Show the solution you are proposing please.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I did; I am proposing to replace `\w` with `[^!]`. Do I really need to copy the entire code block from the question with my changes included?

Comment: Yes, that is the intent of SO. Not everyone will enjoy the same assumptions you may be making about your narrative answer. Comparing your solution with the problem stated gives the OPs of these questions greater understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `\w` does not match whitespace, it matches letters, digits and underscores. Use `[\w\s]` to match either a letter, digit, underscore or whitespace:

```js
const arr = "this! i!s the i!npu!t";
const result = arr.replace(/!([\w\s]+)!/g, '<b>$1</b>');
console.log(result);
```

You can safely remove  the `arr.includes('!')` check because `.replace` command will return unchanged string if no replacement occurs.

Comment: I’d like to upvote your answer, but it includes a change that you haven’t explained: `result` is now a `const`.

Comment: @BrianDrake It is no longer necessary to assign any value to `result` in an `if` block, that is why there no need to use `let`.

Answer (score 0):

If this should not match `! !` to make a space bold `<b> </b>`, and to make the `<b>` start right before the first word character in `! <b>i</b>!` you might also use 3 capturing groups.

If the exclamation marks should pair up, you can use a positive lookahead to assert optional pairs.

```
(!\s*)(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)(\s*!)(?=(?:[^!]*![^!]*!)*[^!]*$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(!\s*)` Capture **group 1**, match ! and optional whitespace chars
- `(\w+(?:\s*\w+)*)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ word chars and optionally repeat matching 1+ whitespace chars and 1+ word chars
- `(\s*!)` Capture **group 3**, match optional whitespace chars and !
- `(?=(?:[^!]*![^!]*!)*[^!]*$)` Positive lookahead, assert optional pairs of ! till the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iCIDA9/1)

If the match should be on the same line, you could exclude matching newlines in the negated character class using `[^!\r\n]`, and use `[^\S\r\n]` to match spaces without newlines instead of `\s`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oUeXDs/1)

```js
const regex = /(!\s*)(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)(\s*!)(?=(?:[^!]*![^!]*!)*[^!]*$)/g;
[
  "this! i!s the i!npu!t",
  "! !",
  "a!a!bb!c!c",
  "a!b!c",
  "xyz",
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(regex, "$1<b>$2</b>$3")));
```